# Act as exclusive handler for custom email attachment types

Tags: ios, email-attachments

I am writing an IOS app that needs to be sent a specific file type via email.  I have this working - I created a custom attachment type, and I handle opening it in my application delegate's openURL: function.  But, when you click on the attachment in the Mail app, it gives you a horizontal list of applications to open the attachment type - such as iMessage, Mail, Notes, Messenger, and some others.  My app is in there too.  So to open the file in my app, you go through the following sequence:

1. Click on the attachment in the Mail app
2. The box pops up asking you to choose the app to open the attachment in
3. You scroll over and choose my app
4. The file is opened in my app.

I would like to skip steps 2 and 3.  Is there any way to do this?  This attachment file is something that will only be handled by my app.  I'd like to register my app as the "exclusive" handler for this custom attachment type.  Or something like that...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt iOS has a facility for this as they would need to extend the options in the Settings app so that the user could specify that they indeed want your app to be the exclusive handler for X file type, otherwise any app could simply hijack an extension and provide a "bad user experience".

Comment: Hmmm.  Maybe you're right.  The thing is - my app is the one and only creator/user of that extension.  Giving the option of opening the attachment in those other apps is silly, there would never be a point.  I'd think there was a way to do it, but maybe not.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I think each side has an equally valid point. Your file type is custom and won't open in anything else and Apple doesn't want photoshop trying to open every image file. I imagine there just wasn't any/much need for this. Perhaps there's a user voice where you can request the feature in the next iOS.